# how to set rails app globally available constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to define a global constant that I can access from anywhere in the application. For this I have created a file in initializer with this content:

```
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(Rails.root + "config/app_config.yml").with_indifferent_access
```

And on a haml view I'm doing this

```
- if APP_CONFIG[:param]
     %b HOLA MUNDO
```

but it says APP_CONFIG is not defined,

I tried using in both places:

```
@@APP_CONFIG
@APP_CONFIG
$APP_CONFIG
```

Nothing works, I also tried with:

```
 module MyApp
  class Application
   APP_CONFIG = .....
  end
 end
```

And from view:

```
MyApp::Application::APP_CONFIG[:param]
```

Also an error
    uninitialized constant MyApp::Application::APP_CONFIG

Answer (score 1):

You would be a lot better wrapping that up in a module. Something like this:

```
    require 'yaml'

    module AppConfig

      class << self
        def settings
          @settings ||= hash.with_indifferent_access
        end

        def path
          File.join(Rails.root, 'config' , 'app_config.yml')
        end

        def hash
          YAML.load_file(path)
        end
      end
    end
```

With that in place, you'll then be able to do this:

```
    puts AppConfig.settings['foo']
```

With the Module you can gathering the data in a number of steps and easily test each step. It will also be easier to extend the behaviour.

And I'd put that in something like app/tools/app_config.rb

Comment: If thats putted on app/tools/ it is automatically loaded on rails 4?

Comment: Yes. All files in the app folder are loaded on app load. Alternatively you could put it in the lib folder and add lib to the load path in the app's configuration.

Comment: Ha! I used this today at WCC :)